# Is creating different CRUD-use cases for every entity in the database obligatory?

Tags: uml, entity, crud, use-case

We are working on a database related to fishes and diseases, with many entities: fish species, fish families, individual fish, and so on. Is it required to split up "manage fishes (CRUD)" into "manage fish species (CRUD)", "manage fish families (CRUD)", "manage individual fish (CRUD)", etc., when they all have the same actors and workflow? Another downside of this is that it requires we keep adding and removing these use cases as we work on our CDM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, of course. However, if they all are treated the same, you likely have a superclass which can be used as placeholder. So for fish, fish species and fish families you should introduce something like (sorry, I'm not familiar here) `fish group` and use that. Now, everywhere you use the term `fish group` this can be substituted with either fish, fish family of fish species.